# Can an EFS file system be mounted to an EC2 instance during creation with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-efs

When you manually create an EC2 instance via the console you have the option of adding an EFS file system as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/gs-step-one-create-ec2-resources.html

Is there a way to mimic this functionality in Terraform?

I am able to create the EFS resource and then add the necessary commands to mount it in the EC2 instance user data but I'm looking for a pure Terraform option similar to the console.

Comment: Note the step in that guide: "For File systems, make sure that the EFS file system that you created in Step 1: Create Your Amazon EFS File System is selected. The path shown next to the file system ID is the mount point that the EC2 instance will use, which you can change. Choose Add to user data to mount the file system when the EC2 is launched." This is just adding it to your user data for you as a convenience feature. To replicate this functionality outside of the console you'd need to do the same as you've already done so.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR. I was hoping for something a little cleaner but I'll just go with that.